# textureImageData in plist? - Cocos 2D V 3.4 (CCParticleSystem)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I am currently fixing up an old Cocos iPhone Xcode project for the new V 3.4 engine. It use to work absolutely fine, however I found this line of code:

```
CCParticleSystem *fire = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"fire.plist"];
```

CCParticleSystemQuad has since been removed therefore I replaced it with "CCParticleSystem":

```
CCParticleSystem *fire = [CCParticleSystem particleWithFile:@"fire.plist"];
```

It kept crashing at that line of code with these error messages:

```
- cocos2d: Couldn't find file:user_particle30956.png
- *** Assertion failure in -[CCTextureCache addCGImage:forKey:], /Users/.../Source/libs/cocos2d-iphone/cocos2d/CCTextureCache.m:370
- *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

The image did not exist and was in fact embedded in the plist file as texture image data. I am aware that in Cocos V 2 it would automatically create and store this texture image data as an image file with a name. **How can I make this work for V 3?**

I'm not sure how much information you need about the plist file. This is the info that follows a long list of particle system configurations (angle, duration, emitter type, etc):

```
<key>textureFileName</key>
<string>user_particle30956.png</string>
<key>textureImageData</key>
<string>eJztnQecXWURxXdDgCCggBQLuisqKlbslcSCBcEC9pa1996wkbUr9q5...</string>
```

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem.  From the [particle designer docs](https://forum.71squared.com/topic/13/embed-a-texture-in-the-particle-system), the embedded texture is apparently TIFF, not PNG which is what Cocos2D expects.

I don't understand this because it used to work just fine with Cocos2D v2.2.

With v3.4.x what I did was change the particle designer project to export the texture as a file and then added that file to the Xcode project so that the particle system would load it the hard way.

You may be able to look at the v2.2 code to see what it did.  Maybe that code can be brought to v3.4.x

[Updated] Having looked at the v2.2 code, the mechanism for taking the binary data from the embedded image and converting it to a texture uses UIImage rather than some PNG/JPEG specific code.

```
// Cocos2d v2.2
//
#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
#elif defined(__CC_PLATFORM_MAC)
            NSBitmapImageRep *image = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:data];
#endif
```

The v3.x code does this (for iOS and Android):

```
// Cocos2D v3.x
//
BOOL png = [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"textureFileName"] lowercaseString] hasSuffix:@".png"];
CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
CGImageRef image = (png) ? CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault) : CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault) ;
```

I strongly suspect that the following might work (though I haven't tested this yet myself):

```
#if __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    [self setTexture:  [ [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:[image CGImage] forKey:textureName]];

#elif __CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
    BOOL png = [[[dictionary valueForKey:@"textureFileName"] lowercaseString] hasSuffix:@".png"];
    CGDataProviderRef imgDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
    CGImageRef image = (png) ? CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault) : CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(imgDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault) ;

    [self setTexture:  [ [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:image forKey:textureName]];

    CGDataProviderRelease(imgDataProvider);
    CGImageRelease(image);
#elif __CC_PLATFORM_MAC
    NSBitmapImageRep *image = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:data];
    [self setTexture:  [ [CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addCGImage:[image CGImage] forKey:textureName]];
#endif
```

I've tried to allow for Android here, but I don't see how it will work if the embedded texture is indeed TIFF, and the Android bridging library also expects PNG/JPEG.